# Find the least number of points (inside triangles formed by vertices of a hexagon)

Tags: geometry

A regular hexagon is given. By joining any three vertices of it we form a triangle - and there are 20 such triangles in total (count as *C* *(6,3)*). We can put anywhere inside the hexagon as many points as we want.

What is the smallest number of points that have to be placed inside the hexagon to get at least one point inside each triangle?

The smallest number of points I have now is 7 (6 near each side and 1 in the center) - can it be less?

Comment: Can you not do it with six points? One near a vertex but not next to an outer edge, and then rotate round $60^\circ$ to get the others

Comment: Yes, got it with 6 points, thanks! Can it be less? My gut feeling tells that not, but no proof at the moment(

Comment: Why you need the point in the center - can you provide a drawing that demonstrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about only 4 points?
Look at the image.

[image: picture]